# How to change order of a bibliography style manually (bilingual bibliography)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

I've got a bilingual bibliography (Russian and German).
I want to sort the entries alphabetically. The Russian entries have to appear alphabetically as well. Unfortunately, since the authors names are written in Russian using the `\cyr` command (for cyrillic), the Russian entries are sorted by the first name of the author, not the second. Is there any possibility to change my `.bst` file?
In `plain.bst` I deleted the sorting function. But now it sorts by the text citation order, which I don't need.

It would be best if there was a style (looking like plain style) which sorts after the source file, i.e. how the entries are made by hand in my `myliterature.bib` file.

Comment: Do you want Russian and German entries mixed in the bibliography with one sort order, or do you want two separate bibliographies?  If the former, how do you decide on the sorting of the two alphabets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With biblatex it's possible to fill a special field used for sorting names; with the standard BibTeX tools one can use

```
author={{\noop{ivanov}}\CYRI\cyrv\cyra\cyrn\cyro\cyrv, \CYRI\cyrv\cyra\cyrn},
```

having put in the document's preamble the definition

```
\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}
```

Of course it's possible to write anything one wants as the argument to `\noop`, for example a common prefix such as `\noop{zzz-ivanov}` would sort all Russian authors at the end.