# Natbib package error? Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Tags: bibliographies, errors, natbib

I'm trying to write an article for a journal using it's LaTeX class and there seems to be an issue with the bibliography.

I'm getting the following error message:

> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

I think that the LaTeX class loads the `natbib` package by default.

I know that `natbib` is a special package for bibliography, but that's all I know about it, and I don't even know how to use it. All I want to do is just be able to compile my LaTeX code without getting any errors.

I've been searching for quick solutions on the internet, but I'm being unable to solve the problem. I tried a couple of things such as replacing the new `natbib` style file with an older version (as suggested somewhere on the internet), but nothing seems to work.

Also, I'm pretty sure I'm formating the references according to the journal's instructions, so I don't know what the problem might be.

If I enter return when the errors occurs, the MikTeX application continues compiling the code and the PDF file is generated without any problems. Anyway, I don't want the `natbib` error to appear because I don't know if the journal will accept the code with this error.

Here's some code I'm using:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{0}
\bibitem{author's last name:year}
author's last name, author's first name initial.
``Author's article.'' 
\textit{journal} (year)

\bibitem{author's last name:year}
author's last name, author's first name initial.
\textit{book title}, edition, p. page number.
place of publication: publisher, year.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Extra information: In the text, I'm able to cite references without any problems by using `\citep`. If I use `\cite`, some text disappears when the code is compiled, and `\citet` won't work.

Comment: Sorry, how do I check the bibliography style?

Comment: @Juan `natbib` is really designed to be used with `bibtex`. So you shouldn't be entering bibliography entries by hand, but into a separated `.bib` file which `bibtex` uses to generate the bibliography items.  See the Bibliographies section of the answer to this question: [What TeX software to write technical papers with](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470/2693).

Comment: In my code there is no "\bibliographystyle{...}". At the top of MikTeX window it says "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX".

Answer (score 3):

Storing your references in a `bibtex` database and using `bibtex` would be the best option. However, if you want to edit manually your bibliography you have to use the appropriate format for `natbit`.

The format of the  bibliography entries for `natbibt` is

```
\bibitem[NameShort(year)NameLong]{citation-label}
author's last name, author's first name initial.
``Author's article.'' 
\textit{journal} (year)
```

`NameShort` can be use to list only the first name an the `et al.` abbreviation. `NameLong` is the full list of authors. `NameShort` is what is used in the majority of cite commands.

Thus, you can modify you `\bibitem` entry as follows

```
\bibitem[Name1 et~al(2012)Name1, Name2, Name3]{cite-label}
...
```

or as follows

```
\bibitem[Name1, Name2, and Name(year){cite label}]
...
```