# Natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Tags: natbib

I have encountered a problem when I wanted to start referencing my work. I get the error

`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`

and it is not even possible to compile the PDF when I undo the cite. The command that I am using is:

```
\ifuseCustomBib
    \RequirePackage[square, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib} 
\fi
```

I am using a bibtex file produced by Mendeley but the weird thing comes when I am not even using the package. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Thank you in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. Incidentally, why are you setting the mutually exclusive and incompatible options `numbers` and `authoryear`? The first option it for numeric-style citation callouts, and the second is for authoryear-style citation call-outs. Choose one or the other option, *but not both*.

Comment: Hi Mico! Thank you for your welcome and your fast reply. So sorry if I am not clear enough but this is my first time using Latex. I used IEEE normative:

    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

However, I have tried what you mention to remove one of them and neither worked out.

Comment: You need to (a) remove the `authoryear` option (since the `ieeetr` bibliography style is not capable of creating authoryear-style citation callouts), (b) delete all auxiliary files (esp. the aux file), (c) run LaTeX again (ignoring any warning messages from LaTeX/natbib), (d) rerun BibTeX, and (e) rerun LaTeX twice more.

Comment: By removing all the auxiliary files it is possible to compile and view the PDF, which I did not know. However, when I try to use `\cite` `\citep` or `\citet` the problem arises again. The console shows:  
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6745 64-bit)  
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux  
...
The style file: ieeetr.bst  
...
I found no \citation commands---while reading file thesis.aux  
Database file #1: References/references.bib  
(There was 1 error message)  
Process exited with error(s)  
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Could [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68924/natbib-package-error-bibliography-not-compatible-with-author-year-citations?rq=1) and its answers help?

Comment: @cjl - If BibTeX complains about an absence of `\cite`-type commands, it's mostly likely because you didn't run LaTeX first after deleting all the aux files. The sequence is LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX.

Comment: @cjl - Since the `ieeetr` bibliography style is only capable of generating numeric-style citation call-outs, it's make much to provide `\citet` instructions. I suggest you change `\citet` instructions to `\cite`. With the option `numbers`, `\citep` behaves like `\cite`, i.e., there's no real need to change the `\citep` instructions.

Comment: Hi @Mico!, I made an attempt with just one single reference and it worked. When I included all the bibiliography, which contains different types and following exactly the same procedureI got the same error. All my cites are `\citet` and the package I am using is `\ifuseCustomBib 
 
\RequirePackage[square, sort, numbers]{natbib}  

\fi`  
Do you have any other idea? By the way, thank you for your awesome support.

Comment: No error while running BibTeX, if helpful.

Comment: @cjl - I don’t understand why you use the `\ifuseCustomBib` conditional. What happens if you get rid of the conditional wrapper?

Comment: If I use  `\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}`
instead of `\ifuseCustomBib  
\RequirePackage[square, sort, numbers]{natbib}  
\fi  
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}` is `"Option clash for package natbib." I received this template to start with so I am not that proficient and I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Problem solved by modifying `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the OP's issues appear to have been solved via comments.