# How does a latex editor work?

Tags: texmaker, windows

I want start writing latex document under windows. So I downloaded texmaker, but I get some errors when I try to create the pdf (command not found "...pdflatex...").

I have to install other things? Or texmaker contains all the necessary?

Comment: You need to also install a TeX distribution. On Windows, you have a choice of either TeX Live or MiKTeX.

Comment: Duplicate of [What TeX software to write technical papers with?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470)

Comment: You should install a distribution prior to TeXmaker. Thus at installation, TeXmaker will know about the distribution.

Comment: Ok thanks, I go to read that answer for more info.