# XeLaTeX compiler file is missing - where shall I download it?

Tags: xetex, compiling

I have a problem with my TeXstudio on Ubuntu, cause I can not compile my tex files via XeLaTeX.

The problem:

> Error: Could not start the command: xelatex -synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode "muktaavalii".tex

I have checked the `src: usr/bin/` but I haven't found the `xelatex` file in the folder.

Could you suggest me something where can I download only that file?

Comment: It is not there. It is on the TeXlive install path.  On terminal, do `which xelatex` (my is `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex`). After that, you just configure TeXstudio to point to that path. See the *Commands* tab on *Option > Configure TeXstudio* menu.

Comment: Hi and welcome, you do have TeX Live installed, right? This is the basic requirement.

Comment: Yeah, but I have TexStudio... :)

Comment: I have checked the folder you've mentioned Sigur, but there is no TexStudio in the local/ directory.

Comment: Don't confuse TeXLive and TeXStudio.

Comment: I know. I use TexStudio.

Comment: TeXLive is better?

Comment: You need both. TeXStudio as editor and TeXlive as texsystem.

Comment: See [What TeX software to write technical papers with?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470) to get an idea of how everything fits together.

Answer (score 5):

Most probably you are missing the XeLaTeX compiler. Install it by running `sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex`. If you haven't installed texlive at all, run `sudo apt-get install texlive`.

To explain what is the difference: TeXStudio is just an editor (like Kate, Gedit, vim, but optimized for LaTeX). TeXLive is a package containing various compilers (which, briefly said, compile tex files into pdfs), LaTeX packages (such as hyperref), language packages and fonts.

Therefore TeXLive is essential if you want to compile tex files. TeXStudio is just a nice bonus to make your editing more pleasant.

Comment: Many Linux users here recommend using the regular TeX Live version rather than the versions packaged by the Linux distros.  See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)