# Tex on Mac (Yosemite)

Tags: mac, mactex

I'm new to Tex and want to install it on my Mac which has OSX Yosemite.

I want to know know the Tex editor which works best with my OS? I saw on it on some forums that MacTeX doesn't work properly on the latest OSX.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to know what TeX system to use on Mac OS X, what editor to use, how updating to Yosemite might affect the two earlier points, or something else?

Comment: MacTeX works very well on Yosemite, excepted the Distribution TeX panel, and that will not hinder you at all (it is useful only if you have several MacTeX installations on your computer). And there is plenty of specific TeX-editors for this platform: TeXShop (which comes with MacTeX), TeXworks, Texmaker, TeXStudio, and so on…

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the reply Joseph.
well I'm a beginner to Tex. So I guess I must learn a bit more about Tex befor installing it on my computer. 

well what I've heard about tex is that it's the best way to write academic papers (according to my University lecturers). 

so can you please advice me, where should I start. I'm bit confused.

Comment: @tikiribanda You might want to read this question: [What TeX software to write technical papers with?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470)

Comment: @yo' Thanx. I will check this out.

Comment: @fpast. Thanx. I will try this! :D