# Spanish bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, spanish

I've written my bibliography as a standard bib entry; e.g.:

```
@ARTICLE{Imanishi1960,
AUTHOR="Kinji Imanishi",
TITLE="Social Organization of Subhuman Primates in Their Natural Habitat",
JOURNAL="Current Anthropology",
VOLUME="1",
ISSUE="5",
PAGES="393--407",
YEAR="1960",
}
```

However, I wish the bibliography to be printed in Spanish, not English.
I understand I need to use the biblatex package, and I've done so. Here is a copy of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{Palabras clave:}\quad #1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{spanish}
\setbtxfallbacklanguage{spanish}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\title{El animalismo es un humanismo}
\author{Javier García-Salcedo \textemdash{ Ana Amezcua Ferrer}}
\date{Agosto 2016}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

However, after a couple of compilations, the language of my bibliography is still being English--e.g. the computer prints "Bekoff, M. **and** Pierce, J." *au lieu de* "Bekoff, M. **y** Pierce, J.", etc.

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not actually using `biblatex`, but the `babelbib` package, which uses standard `bibtex`. Since I think it's a good idea to use `biblatex` perhaps you should look at [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509).

Comment: What a fool. You're right. I've been looking through the link you posted, learning a lot. Thanks for your feedback, @AlanMunn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your document is not actually using `biblatex`. But I think it's a good idea to use, so here's a basic example document showing you how to do this. You should also take a look at:

- [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/2693)
- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib)

The following document needs to be compiled with `pdflatex` and then `biber` (not `bibtex`) and then `pdflatex` again.

Please note that I have included a couple of `.bib` items in the source file to make the file self-contained so that it doesn't depend on reference to a `.bib` file specific to my (or your) setup. In practice, you wouldn't do this, but you would have a separate `.bib` file named however you like. The use of `\jobname.bib` is also only part of making a self-contained example; it ensures that the file generated by this example document is unlikely to overwrite any other file on your system.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{VelazquesCastillo2005,
    Address = {Mexico City and Quer{\'e}taro},
    Author = {Vel{\'a}zquez Castillo, M.},
    Booktitle = {Dimensiones del Aspecto en Espa{\~n}ol},
    Editor = {Maldonado, R. and Lubbers Quesada, M.},
    Pages = {173-193},
    Publisher = {Universidad Nacional Aut{\'o}noma de M{\'e}xico and Universidad Aut{\'o}noma de Quer{\'e}taro},
    Title = {Aspecto Verbal en el Espa{\~n}ol Paraguayo: Elementos del Sustrato},
    Year = {2005}}

@article{VelazquesCastilloHudgens2013,
    Author = {Vel{\'a}zquez Castillo, M. and Hudgens, M.},
    Journal = {Journal of Pidgin and Creole Languages},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {65-102},
    Title = {Quiero para mi novio. Aspectual uses of \emph{para} in {Paraguayan Spanish}},
    Volume = {28},
    Year = {2013}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{VelazquesCastillo2005,VelazquesCastilloHudgens2013}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks again! I currently use Miktex as editor and compiler (I'm really a newbie concerning Latex so please, if I say something that makes no sense, be charitable!). As far as I can see, 'Miktex' does not have 'biber'. Does this mean that I have to check on the web for another Tex editor?

Comment: @JavierGarcía-Salcedo MikTeX is a distribution, not an editor, and it certainly comes with `biber`. This question should help orient yourself about all the various components of using LatTeX: [What TeX software to write technical papers with?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470). So you need to figure out how to use `biber` with the editor you are using. Here's a question that should help on that: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)

Comment: I have a doubt, though, concerning your document. I can see the bibliographic info is included before the specification of the document class. Does this mean that, in order to use biblatex, I  must not create a separate .bib file--that my bibliography need to be placed before the \documentclass command?

Comment: @JavierGarcía-Salcedo No, not at all. This is just a way to include a file in an example document. You would not do this in practice, but would have a separate `.bib` file. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the answer.  And the use of `\jobname.bib` is so that the file chosen is dependent on whatever you save the source file as, which helps prevent overwriting an existing file.  Again, you wouldn't do that in your actual document.

Comment: @JavierGarcía-Salcedo Since I think this answer solved your problem, it's helpful also to "Accept" it by clicking on the  checkmark below the voting arrows.

Comment: I've successfully configured my TeXworks editor in order for it compile .bib files with biber, as shown in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations]. But when I try to compile the document (which is the same you included (\begin...\end{filecontents})). However, when I run with biber, I got this: INFO - This is Biber 2.5
INFO - Logfile is 'TryOut1biblatex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'TryOut1biblatex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1. So how can I pass the backend ... option to BibLaTeX??

Comment: @JavierGarcía-Salcedo Try deleting all the auxiliary files (everything except the `.tex` and `.bib` file, and try again. That should be the default setting for `biblatex`, but you can also add `backend=biber` to the options passed to `biblatex` (i.e., `\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]` although it shouldn't be necessary with a recent distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do, is to add `language={spanish}` inside every bibliography item in your `.bib`-file. For example:

```
@article{Aguilar2011,
    author =       "A Aguilar and M Vicarelli",
    title =        "El Niño and Mexican children: Medium-term effects of early-life weather shocks on cognitive and health outcomes",
    journal =      "",
    volume =       "",
    number =       "",
    pages =        "",
    year =         "2011",
    url =          "",
    note =         "Working paper"
    language = {spanish}
}
```