# Sorting bibliography references using the Vancouver style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

I am new to LaTeX and I would like to be able to sort my references with the Vancouver style but I don´t know if I need to include some libraries or do something else?

I have searched around the web but I am very confused, I have found something like this

```
 \cite{key} ==>>          [#]
```

but it does not work, I hope you can help

Comment: The only 3rd party file you have to include is the BibTeX style file `vancouver.bst` with the following command `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}` (assuming the `.tex` and the `.bst` files are in the same folder).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

For an overview of how LaTeX and BibTeX work, generally, see:

- [What TeX software to write technical papers with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470/2693)

Here's a simple example:

Assume your `.bib` file looks like this:

**testbib.bib**

```
@article{Hudson-et-al1982,
    Author = {Hudson, Lynne M and Guthrie, Karen H and Santilli, Nicholas R},
    Journal = {Journal of Child Language},
    Month = {Feb},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {125-138},
    Title = {The Use of Linguistic and Non-Linguistic Strategies in Kindergarteners' Interpretations of 'More' and 'Less'},
    Volume = {9},
    Year = {1982}}
```

(You can create these entries using your favourite reference manager (most likely JabRef (Windows/Linux/Mac) or BibDesk (Mac).  See:

- [Is there a citation manager which plays nicely with BibTeX and has automatic metadata import from PDFs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42361/2693)

Now create a document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\begin{document}
This is a citation in the text\cite{Hudson-et-al1982}.
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```

Compile this using `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, then `pdflatex` and `pdflatex` once more.
For more on why this is necessary, see:

- [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/2693)

  The resulting document should look like this:

[image: output of code]