# How to force a specific entry to be first in the bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

I'm writing a paper and I need a specific entry in the bibliography go first in the list. The rest of entries should be sorted as usual. I use `plain` bibliography style and an external `.bib` file.

For example: there are three authors: Jack Alien, John Bravo and Ally Complex and their papers will be sorted in references as [1] Alien, [2] Bravo, [3] Complex. But I'd like it to be: [1] Complex, [2] Alien, [3] Bravo.

I know, that I can do something like in [How to change order of a bibliography style manually (bilingual bibliography)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18636/how-to-change-order-of-a-bibliography-style-manually-bilingual-bibliography), but the single `.bib` file is used in many projects and in those projects the references should be sorted in standard way.

So, how to accomplish, that a specific reference will be placed first in the bibliography?

Comment: You need *one* entry in *one* document to go first? It is surely easiest to make a duplicate entry (but with a unique key) of that one entry that uses the trick in the linked to question, and just cite that entry in this one-off document and then not cite it in everything else.  If you are going to do fancy sorting things frequently, you should consider switching to `biber`+`biblatex`.

Comment: @jon Yes, exactly -- _one_ entry in _one_ document. And your comment is a solution for me. Post your comment as an answer to let me mark it. Thanks!

Comment: Make a copy of the `.bib` file and modify that one. If the change is just for *one* article, it's the simplest way to go. Otherwise, switch to `biblatex`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a one-off document where there is only one (or very few) entries that require special sorting treatment, it is not unreasonable to create a 'special' entry and use that entry instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{adams1986,
  author =   {Adams, Anthony},
  title =    {Article Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     1986,
  volume =   46,
  pages =    {1--35},
}
@Article{zedson2013,
  author =   {Zedson, John},
  title =    {Zarticle title},
  journal =      {Journal},
  year =     2013,
  volume =   22,
  pages =    {141--181},
}
@Article{zedson2013-special,
  author =   {{\noop{AAA}}Zedson, John},
  title =    {Zarticle title},
  journal =      {Journal},
  year =     2013,
  volume =   22,
  pages =    {141--181},
  annote =       {NOTE: use for special sorting},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\cite{adams1986}
\cite{zedson2013}
\cite{zedson2013-special}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

If you use `biber`, an easy way to achieve unorthodox/special sorting is to add a `sortkey = {<sortkey>}` to the entry in question.  From the `biblatex` manual (§ 2.2.3):

> A field used to modify the sorting order of the bibliography. Think of
>   this field as the master sort key. If present, biblatex uses this
>   field during sorting and ignores everything else, except for the
>   presort field. Please refer to § 3.5 for further details. This field
>   is consumed by the backend processing and does not appear in the .bbl.

If only using (an alphabetical) `biblatex` (style) with `BibTeX` as the backend, you can do something similar by utilizing the `sortname` field.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution:

Just add

```
\begin{document}
\nocite{refName}
```

and it will force that reference to be the first entry in the bib, assuming you are using a bib style that sorts by order of appearance, like IEEE (with other styles, you can disable alphabetical order via commands like `usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}`).

Comment: If I wanted to use a ,,sort by order of appearance'' style, I would not ask the question ;). BTW, I'd like to point out, that in the question I noted I used `plain` style (which uses alphabetical sorting), so your solution, in fact, isn't an answer for my question.

Comment: Yes, but for some other sorting function, e.g., using `IEEEtran`, this works correctly.