# Reordering BibTex entries

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm using bibtex and in the reference part it automatically orders entries alphabetically in the author. This is what I want, the problem is that one of the entries has a compound name `Joachim von zur Gathen`. And its taking the `von` to order it, when it should be `Gathen`. How can I change it?

Comment: That's the behavior of the standard BibTeX styles. Which one are you declaring with `\bibliographystyle`?

Comment: @egreg `abbrv`.

Comment: There are often better ways, but since you haven't provided much detail about your document(s), I can only suggest the old generic trick: in your `.bib` file, put `@preamble{ "\providecommand{\noop}[1]{}" }` and then use `author = {\noop{Gathen}von zur Gathen, Joachim},`.

Comment: @jon That works, so I'm good with it. If you copy it in an answer I will accept it :). Thank you very much

Comment: It's a duplicate question/answer, I think.  See, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115300/8528