# Ordering bibliography is not working

Tags: bibliographies

I recently asked a question to know how to modify the order of bibliography, as one of the authors had a compound name and didn't appear (alphabetically) where it should be.

The question was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245435/reordering-bibtex-entries), and it has an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18636/how-to-change-order-of-a-bibliography-style-manually-bilingual-bibliography).

When  I first did it it worked, but for some reason it doesn't work now. I have at the beggining of my .bib file the line

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\noop}[1]{}"}
```

And when including that reference, I have;

```
author = {\noop{Gathen} Joachim von zur Gathen and Jürguen Gerhard}
```

When I compile via `latex,biblatex,latex,latex`. It appears like this in the references part:

[image]

Between the `N` and the `P`. Why is this?

I'm using the article class. Is there something wrong with that?

I suppose it's with how I write the name, as the style I'm using abbreviates the first name of all authors, but is keeping this one full (`Joachim`).

EDIT: I include a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,english,es-tabla]{babel}

\begin{document}
\cite{CA}, \cite{NAT}, \cite{UC}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

The bib file would contain:

```
@Book{UC,
author = {Christof Paar and Jan Pelzl},
title = {Understanding Cryptography},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {2010}
}

@Book{CA,
author = {\noop{A} {von zur Gathen}, Joachim and Jürguen Gerhard},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {Modern Computer Algebra},
publisher = {Cambridge Univ. Press},
year = {2003},
edition = {second}
}

@Book{NAT,
  author =   {Melvyn B. Nathanson},
  ALTeditor =    {},
  title =        {Elementary methods in Number Theory},
  publisher =    {Springer},
  year =         {2000}}
```

That reproduces the same order as in the picture above.

Comment: very silly question ... did you delete the `.bbl` file and rerun bibtex after making the change in the `.bib` file?  another silly question ... have you tried the arrangement with the comma and the braces around `{von zur Gathen}` *without* the `\noop`?  that looks like the "prescribed" format to me.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Removing the `bbl` does not change anything. Removing the `\noop` puts it at the end of the references, sorting it by the 'v', where it should be sorted by the 'G'

Comment: okay.  bibtex is supposed to ignore "particles" (like "von" and "zur") so omitting the braces and just using the comma format has a good chance of giving you what you want.  by the way, the only reason i can think why this name would sort between "Na" and "P" is that the string "`noop`" is being taken literally; i'm not sure how bibtex handles that coding, and i've never used it for an author's name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the whole `\noop{...}{...}` in braces:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{UC,
author = {Christof Paar and Jan Pelzl},
title = {Understanding Cryptography},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {2010},
}

@Book{CA,
author = {{\noop{Gathen}{von zur Gathen}}, Joachim and Jürguen Gerhard},
title = {Modern Computer Algebra},
publisher = {Cambridge Univ. Press},
year = {2003},
edition = {second},
}

@Book{NAT,
  author =   {Melvyn B. Nathanson},
  title =        {Elementary methods in Number Theory},
  publisher =    {Springer},
  year =         {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,english,es-tabla]{babel}

\providecommand{\noop}[2]{#2}

\begin{document}
\cite{CA}, \cite{NAT}, \cite{UC}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents*` just to make the example self-contained, use a separate file without worries.

[image]

Comment: I accept this answer as being the easiest way to solve it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

If you compile with `bilatex+biber` you don't need `\noop` nor braces:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,english,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@Book{UC,
author = {Christof Paar and Jan Pelzl},
title = {Understanding Cryptography},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {2010}
}

@Book{CA,
author = {von zur Gathen, Joachim and Jürguen Gerhard},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {Modern Computer Algebra},
publisher = {Cambridge Univ. Press},
year = {2003},
edition = {2}
}

@Book{NAT,
author = {Melvyn B. Nathanson},
ALTeditor = {},
title = {Elementary methods in Number Theory},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[firstinits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{CA}, \cite{NAT}, \cite{UC}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]