# Surname of author which I am citing starts with a small letter, but it's at the beginning of the sentence - how to make it capitalized?

Tags: citing

In the article that I am writing, one of the authors that I am citing is from Netherlands and his surname contains the 'van der' phrase. So, in contrast to most other authors' surnames, which start with capital letters, this author's surname starts with a small letter.

I want to use `\textcite{thisauthor}` at the beginning of the sentence, but what it does then is that it generates the citation like anywhere else in the text - with the small 'van der'. However, since it is at the beginning of the sentence, I need it to look like this: 'Van der'. How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Then we know which packages and setup your're using and thus it is a lot easier to help

Comment: Please confirm that you use the `biblatex` package,

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40747/bibtex-handling-of-the-dutch-van-name-prefix-with-natbib

Answer (score 1):

If you use Biblatex then there is a command `\Textcite` (with capital T) that forces the first letter of a name prefix to be in upper case. This requires the package option `useprefix=true` to display the prefix in the first place.

From the Biblatex [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), currently (version 3.17, 2022-02-02) section 3.9.2 *Style-specific commands* on page 110:

> `\Textcite` is similar to `\textcite` but capitalizes the name prefix of the first name in the citation if the `useprefix` option is enabled, provided that there is a name prefix.

The `useprefix` option will also sort the name under the prefix, which is not desired - in Dutch and in several other languages that use prefixes they should not be used for sorting. You can revert this behavior by explicitly setting the sort order, as in [Prefixes in author names in references and bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440133/prefixes-in-author-names-in-references-and-bibliography).

Similar capitalized versions exist for other cite commands, like `\Autocite`.

MWE (`.bib` file):

```
@phdthesis{thisauthor,
   author = {van der Waals, Johannes Diderik},
   title = {On the continuity of the gas and liquid state},
   school = {Leiden University},
   year = {1873}
}
```

MWE (`.tex` file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate{
  \keypart{
    \namepart{family}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{prefix}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{given}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{suffix}
  }
}
\addbibresource{citecase.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{thisauthor} studied thermodynamics.

\Textcite{thisauthor} studied thermodynamics.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If, instead of Biblatex, you use the `natbib` package then there are also capitalized versions of cite commands available. From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf), currently page 9:

> **2.5 Forcing Upper Cased Name**
> If the first author's name contains a *von* part, such as "della Robbia", then `\citet{dRob98}` produces "della Robbia (1998)", even at the beginning of a sentence. One can
> force the first letter to be in upper case with the command `\Citet`
> instead. Other upper case commands also exist.
>
> when `\citet{dRob98}` ⇒ della Robbia (1998)
> then
> `\Citet{dRob98}` ⇒ Della Robbia (1998)
> `\Citep{dRob98}` ⇒ (Della Robbia, 1998)
> `\Citealt{dRob98}` ⇒ Della Robbia 1998
> `\Citealp{dRob98}` ⇒ Della Robbia, 1998
> `\Citeauthor{dRob98}` ⇒ Della Robbia
>
> These commands also exist in starred versions for full author names.
> Note: the coding for the upper casing commands is tricky and likely
> buggy. It operates on the names that are stored in the `\bibitem`
> entry, and works even if old style font commands are used; however,
> LaTeX2ε commands will cause it to crash. Thus
> `\bibitem[{\it della Robbia}(1998)]{dRob98}` is ok, but
> `\bibitem[\textit{della Robbia}(1998)]{dRob98}` crashes.

MWE: (`.tex` file)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citeauthor{thisauthor} studied thermodynamics \citep{thisauthor}.

\Citeauthor{thisauthor} studied thermodynamics \citep{thisauthor}.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{citecase}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Correct sorting in this case can be done from within the `.bib` file, see for example [Ordering bibliography is not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251358/ordering-bibliography-is-not-working).

Comment: The answer is the same for `biblatex`: Just use the command you want to use, but capitalise its first letter. I.e. `\Autocite` instead of `\autocite` or `\Textcite` instead of `\textcite`.

Comment: I commented with the `biblatex` "solution" above since the question explicitly mentions `\textcite`, which is not defined by default by `natbib` (or any other BibTeX/`thebibliography`-based citation package as far as I know), so `biblatex` is more likely to be relevant here than `natbib`.

Comment: @moewe I see now, I misread the question thinking it mentioned `\citeauthor` while it clearly did not. Maybe it can still be useful for future readers though, I could add a Biblatex MWE for completeness (and to answer the OP properly).

Comment: @moewe I added a Biblatex version to cover both usage scenarios.