# using bibtex+babelbib to sort and construct label of bibliography item in Russian Cyrillic

Tags: bibtex

I've selected the [`babelbib` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babelbib), in cooperation with `babel`, to generate a single bibliography with `bibtex` containing items written in English and Russian Cyrillic.

I'm using the bibliography style `babalpha`, a `babelbib` equivalent of the standard `alpha` BibTeX style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % russian requires T2A
\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}
   \usepackage{babelbib}

\bibliographystyle{babalpha}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{master}
\end{document}
```

The entries in the `master.bib` file, for which `babelbib` requires the additional `language` field, are:

```
@book{ponomarenko86,
      author = "Пономаренко, Л. А. and Адамович, Л. В. 
            and Музычук,     В. Т. and Гридасов, А. Е.",
      title = {{Основы создания гибких атоматизированных производств}},
      publisher = "Технiка",
      year = "1986",
      language = "russian"
      }

@book{biblarz01,
      author = "Biblarz, Oscar and Sutton, George P. and Schroeder, Matt and King, Benjamin",
      title = {{Rocket Propulsion Elements}},
      publisher = "John Wiley \&{} Sons, Inc.",
      year = "2001",
      language = "english"
      }

@manual{encyclopediavolI-60,
        organization = {{U.S. Army RDECOM-ARDEC}},
        title = {{Encyclopedia of Explosives And Related Items, volume 1}},
        year = "1960",
        key = "US",
        language = "english"
        }

@manual{instr86,
        organization = {{Министерство обороны СССР, Орден Трудового Красного Знамени}},
        title = {{Типовая инструкция по эксплуатации топливоподачи
                  тепловых электростанций: ТИ 34-70-044-85}},
        year = "1986",
        key = "USS",
        language = "russian"
        }
```

This produces:
[image]

The surnames in the first entry (key: `ponomarenko86`) can be transliterated as **P**onomarenko, **A**damovich, **M**uzyčuk and **G**ridasov.

I would like the first entry to be printed exactly as it is, yet sort it under "Ponomarenko", and produce the label [PAMG86]. (`babalpha.bst` only produces a label with `+` for entries with 5 or more authors.)

Are these things possible with `babelbib`? Should I migrate to `biblatex`?

---

What I've tried so far:

- Put `@preamble{"\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{}"}` at the beginning of my `.bib` file, then use `author = "{\noopsort{Ponomarenko}}Пономаренко, Л. А. ..."`. This approach sorts the entry under "Ponomarenko", but fails to produce the right label and seems to fiddle with the indentation of every bibliography item. [image]
- Use an entry type with no mandatory `author` or `editor` field (like `manual` and `misc`), allowing me to specify my own `key` field. The problem is that these produce somewhat different results.

Comment: Related question: [How to change order of a bibliography style manually (bilingual bibliography)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18636/14497).

Answer (score 3):

The recently developed [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) package, replacing BibTeX's style files with easy-to-structure templates, deals with multiple languages easily and can provide the OOP's requested behavior. Using the following `.tex` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % russian requires T2A
\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{example}
\bibliography{master}
\end{document}
```

without changing the `.bib` file, we can write a style template file like the following

```
TEMPLATES:
book = [<au>|<ed>|<organization>|<institution>|], \textit{<title>} (<publisher>, <year>).[ <note>]
manual = [<au>|<ed>|<organization>|<institution>|], \textit{<title>}, (<organization>, <year>).[ <note>]

SPECIAL-TEMPLATES:
citelabel = [<key><year.-2:-1>|<citealpha>|]
sortkey = <citelabel>
```

This either uses the `key` variable if defined in the database entry, and adds the last two digits of the `year` variable, or makes use of the native `citealpha` variable that emulates the `alpha` style used in BiBTeX. With these inputs, the formatted output looks like

[image]